# I am not getting the output printed on python idle using tkinter

Tags: tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
```

here i am printing the data given by user in the def save_info section, my GUI is working. but after pressing submit button, data is not displayed on the promt screen.

```
#Printing input data
def save_info():
    email_info = email.get()
    name_info  = name.get()
    mobileno_info = mobileno.get()
    print(email_info, name_info, mobileno_info)

# Making Screen
screen = Tk()
screen.geometry( "800x800" )
screen.title( "Assignment" )
heading = Label( text="Tkinter", bg="red", width="600", height="2" )
heading.pack()

# Input From User
email_text   = Label(text="Email :")
name_text    = Label(text= "Name :")
mobno_text  = Label(text="Mobile Number :")
email_text.place(x=15, y=70)
name_text.place(x=15, y=140)
mobno_text.place(x=15, y=210)

# Entry Fields
email = StringVar()
name  = StringVar()
mobileno = IntVar()

email_input = Entry(textvariable = email, width="40")
name_input  = Entry(textvariable = name,width="40")
mobileno_input = Entry(textvariable = mobileno, width="40")

#Entry Place
email_input.place(x=15, y=100)
name_input.place(x=15, y=170)
mobileno_input.place(x=15, y=240)

# Submit Button
submit = Button(text="Submit", width="33", height="2", bg="grey")
submit.place(x=15,y=280)
```

Comment: You did not assign a function to `command` option of the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is missing a command.

Change:

```
submit = Button(text="Submit", width="33", height="2", bg="grey")
```

To:

```
submit = Button(text="Submit", width="33", height="2", bg="grey", command=save_info)
```

That said you should change a couple things.

1. Do not use `import *` this can cause you to overwrite imports and other methods.
   Use `import tkinter as tk` instead and then use the `tk.` prefix for your widgets and other tkinter code.
2. Do not use `place()` for general widget placement. `pack()` and `grid()` are typically what you want to use and they are easier to maintain. The `place()` manager has its uses but there is nothing here that should be using it.